# Table view cell isn't transparent until I force the cell to reload?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` with a `UIImageView` as its background. I want to display some transparent cells in the table so that I can see the background image through the cell's background image.

So far, I'm setting the cell's `backgroundView` to a `UIImageView` with a custom `alpha` and setting the background image view's `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`. I'm also setting the cell's `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

When the cell is initially drawn, I still see a white background. However, if I drag the cell off the screen, it's transparent when it comes back on. Anyone have any idea what's up with that?

Edit: Here's some code, though I don't think it really tells you anything more than what I said above. Some sensitive/irrelevant stuff is edited out.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        ...
        _backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self contentView] bounds]];
        [_backgroundImageView setAlpha:0.5];
        [_backgroundImageView setOpaque:NO];
        [_backgroundImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self setBackgroundView:_backgroundImageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [_backgroundImageView setFrame:rect];
}

// in a different file
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: {
    ...
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setOpaque:NO];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Tried setting the background image view's `opaque` to `NO` as well as the cell itself. Didn't help.

Comment: Are all these properties set via Interface Builder? Try writing those in code in the cell controller's "awakeFromNib" method.

Comment: Nope, the whole cell is drawn in code. I'm currently setting the alphas and stuff in `drawRect:` though... maybe I should be doing that somewhere else?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a good place to put the code. Are you subclassing the cell views? What for?

Comment: Please post your code so we can all help you.

Comment: Yeah, this is in a cell subclass because I have to do some custom drawing in the cell. Where else would I set up stuff if not `drawRect:`? `layoutSubviews`? Hold on I'll post some code, I'll have to edit out some irrelevant stuff first.

Comment: Code posted. I wasn't really doing much in `drawRect:` anyway.

Comment: What does your view hierarchy look like?

Comment: Figured it out, it was actually my table view's custom background view doing something stupid. Sorry, I totally overlooked that part of my code and didn't post it because I assumed I wasn't an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: I'm not even doing anything in `drawRect:` relevant to the cell transparency.

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [_backgroundImageView setFrame:rect];
}
```

add this

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [_backgroudImageVIew setFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
}
```

why are you doing this:

```
[_backgroundImageView setAlpha:0.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. This was actually due to a weird interaction of `UITableView` with the cells, not the cells themselves. As I mentioned, I'm using a custom table view with a `UIImageView` background, but I made the mistake of delaying setting the table view's `backgroundView` property to the image view until `drawRect:` instead of doing it in `init` or `awakeFromNib` or anywhere else that would make sense.

Setting the background view of the table view actually changes what the cells do for some reason. Previously, when I was changing the background view in `drawRect:`, the cells would be drawn as if the table view had a white background, then update when they got redrawn. Now that I've moved things into an initializer method everything's fine.

Sorry, I didn't provide code for the table view because it didn't even occur to me that it could be causing the problem (nor did it occur to me that I was an idiot and put a line of code in the wrong method... don't code at 4 AM :/)